# how to install library modules on python version which is not default

Tags: python

I have python 2.7 by default and 2.6 but I need some modules installed on python 2.6 .But by default it is installing on 2.7.Any idea how to do it.

Comment: Perhaps virtualenv can helps you?

Comment: You should consider using [`virtualenv`](http://pypi.python.org/pypi/virtualenv). See this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1534210/use-different-python-version-with-virtualenv

Comment: Suppose I have to install following pckgs on python 2.6. 
Django-1.3.1-py2.6.egg
django_autocomplete-1.0.dev49-py2.6.egg
django_ajax_selects-1.2.3-py2.6.egg

how can we do it using virtualenv..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you explicitly call your Python 2.6 Binary when installing the package it will install to that instance instead.  So instead of `python setup.py install` you would do `/path/to/python26 setup.py install`.